# Create new Rails project with previous rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The latest version of rails installed on my mac is 3.0.0.beta

gem list returns
rails (3.0.0.beta, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.2, 2.2.2, 1.2.6)

I want to create a new project using version 2.3.5

So I run: `rails _2.3.5_ myProject`

But it returns the following error

```
$ rails _2.3.5_ photosbackup
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: railties(3.0.0.beta not = 2.3.5) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Any idea how I can create a new project using version 2.3.5?

Thanks

Comment: answer here http://codename30.com/2010/02/22/generating-rails-app-in-previous-version-after-rails-3-0-beta/ - ps. this appears to be a known issue although the bug has not yet been assigned https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3923-enhancement-request-generate-application-using-previous-rails-version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just uninstall the previous Rails versions.

Which can be problematic - I have a number of Rails 2.3.5 (and earlier) apps in production that require maintenance and won't be upgraded to the new version.

So what I recommend in this situation is having a look at [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) - it lets you install and manage multiple versions of Ruby, and provides isolation between sets of Gems. I now run a Ruby 1.9.1 with Rails 3 and friends in isolation from my default system settings which let me do my day to day work.

Comment: +1 for the RVM advice - I posted a link up top to a blog post that should help fix the problem - the user would probably still get the same error whilst using RVM but life is SOOOO much easier when you are using RVM...  I freaking love it

Comment: i am already working with macports. That wouldn't work with RVM right?

Comment: rvm is totally separate to macports and should work. Creates a whole new self-contained ruby environment outside of the existing os stuff.

Answer (score -1):

even i had the same problem but the following command worked for me
rails *2.3.5* new myProject